How do I target certain elements when using MUI for Gsap animation in next.js?
I'm trying to animate a Typography component from MUI in a Next.js project using the useGSAP hook from GSAP 4. Despite following the setup, the animation isn't working. Here is my code:
"use client";

import { Box, Button, Container, Typography, boxClasses } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { useGSAP } from "@gsap/react";
import gsap from "gsap";

const Nav = () => {
  const logo = useGSAP((el) => {
    gsap.to(el, {
      y: 1000,
      duration: 1,
    });
  });

 return (
    <>
      <Container
        sx={{
          bgcolor: "primary.light",
          height: "13vh",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          width: "100%",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
        maxWidth={false}
      >
        <Box>
          <Typography ref={logo} variant="h2" sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
            Logo
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", gap: "2vh", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Typography variant="h5">About us</Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">Contact</Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">More</Typography>
          <Button color="secondary" variant="contained">
            click here
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

Iam a complete beginner in both react and MUI but i have lot experience with GSAP so any answer would be helpful :)
